# Read a single column of a CSV for API Call

Tags: python, json, api, csv, automation

How can I do such a task in python? I got a *CSV* file with a bunch of parameters, let's say *"col"* and *"para"*. So, I would like to loop all the parameters in *"para"* column as an array and get every response data back and write into *CSV* file?

| col | para | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | e |  |
| b | f |  |
| c | g |  |

like

```py
para = [e,f,g]
```

After having this array, then I can use every one of them for API query. For instance, http://api.com/query?name=e will return a *JSON* response like this

```py
{
 "data":[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "e",
  "response":"return e from api" 
 }, {
  "id": 11,
  "name": "second ",
  "response":"return seconde from api" 
 }
]
}
```

After retrieving the response data from API call, then it can be written into *CSV* file in return column.

So finally, I'm looking for the table will be something like below

| col | para | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | e | return e from api |
| b | f | return f from api |
| c | g | return g from api |

Comment: Which kind of API it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `apply()` function for DataFrame. This function can do the same operation for each element of one column.

[How to use apply function in pandas](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations/classes/pandas%20columns%20and%20functions/apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/)

Here is the example for your case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

data = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv") 
url = "http://api.com/query?name={}"

data['return'] = data['para'].apply(lambda x:requests.get(url.format(x)).text)

data.to_csv("output_file.csv",index=False)
```

For more process, you can define a function to replace `lambda` function above:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def my_process(para):
    url = "http://api.com/query?name={}".format(para)
    try:
        return_json = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
        response = return_json['data'][0]['response'] # get the first response string
    except:
        response = ""  # set a value for the case that the API call has no correct results
    return response

data = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv") 
data['return'] = data['para'].apply(my_process)

data.to_csv("output_file.csv",index=False)
```

```
<ipython-input-29-77b593e201eb> in <module>
     11 
     12 data = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
---> 13 data['return'] = data['para'].apply(my_process)
     14 
     15 data.to_csv("output_file.csv",index=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-29-77b593e201eb> in my_process(para)
      6     url = "http://api.com/query?name={}".format(para)
      7     return_json = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
----> 8     response = return_json['data'][0]['response '] # get the first response string
      9     return response
     10
```

Comment: so, I don't need to loop every one of them?

Comment: No, you don't. You can attempt the codes above

Comment: It's very nice, cuz ive been using a for loop to do that, didn't think it can does the same thing.
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "e",
  "response":"return e from api" 
 }
]

What if I want to get only the string for "response" field back to the csv?

Comment: get the string value from "response" key back into csv.

Comment: There might be return more than 1 responses with same parameter, how can get the first one and its string value

Comment: @pakwai122 It's useful for you to learn the ```apply``` function in your case, I've added the code in the answer, you can look it as a reference.

Comment: I've used your new code and able to print the string response from the API, but it cannot be returned and get an error. "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: that's the problem of your API call, for some paras, it returns empty value, so the ```my_process()```function can not get the first response string(it doesn't exist!)

Comment: thank you for your help. you're really helpful. thank you again.